# Error when running the SSIS packae from SQL server 2005 Job agent

Tags: ssis, package

Executed as user: STRATEGIC\administrator. ...4035.00 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.    Started:  11:01:26 AM  Progress: 2010-11-22 11:01:26.97     Source: Copy Data into Temp Table      Validating: 0% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2010-11-22 11:01:26.97     Source: Copy Data into Temp Table      Validating: 50% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2010-11-22 11:01:27.03     Source: Copy Data into Temp Table      Validating: 100% complete  End Progress  Warning: 2010-11-22 11:01:27.03     Code: 0x80047076     Source: Copy Data into Temp Table DTS.Pipeline     Description: The output column "PoBox" (56) on output "Flat File Source Output" (2) and component "Flat File Source" (1) is not subsequently used in the Data Flow task. Removing this unused output column can increase Data Flow task performance.  End Warning  Warning: 2010-11-22 11:01:27.03     Code: 0x80047076     Source: Copy Data into Temp Table DTS.Pipeline     Des...  Process Exit Code 1.  The step failed.

Comment: Rather than an error dump, could you explain what is happening in the package, particularly the step that fails?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in your output that explains why the step would fail.  You will need to provide additional information.  The only portion in the dump that is useful is this part (which caused a warning -- not a failure):

```
Source: Copy Data into Temp Table DTS.Pipeline Description: The output column "PoBox" (56) on output "Flat File Source Output" (2) and component "Flat File Source" (1) is not subsequently used in the Data Flow task. Removing this unused output column can increase Data
```

Just means you have a column in your source that isn't mapped to something in the destination.  Therefore, you could either remove the field from the source load or deselect it in the source so that it isn't available to subsequent portions of the pipeline.